# How do I store uploads on a hosting application?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, server, multer

Good evening all. So I have created a React Application that accepts and stores images locally along with storing it on MongoDB with some additional data. It works perfectly fine, all functionalities work well in local development. However, when I upload the server side of it to Heroku, and use that URL for send axios requests, It gives errors such as below
[ERRORS IN CONSOLE WHEN USING SERVER FROM HEROKU APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AXOa.png)

I do have however, the cors configured as such in the server

```
app.use(
  cors({
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE", "UPDATE", "PUT", "PATCH"],
  })
);
```

This is also where I store my files locally when I upload, in an uploads folder

```
//storage area for uploads
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req,file,cb) =>{
        cb(null,'uploads')
    },
    filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
        cb(null,file.originalname)
    }
})

const upload = multer({storage:storage});
```

And this is my post Function handler

```
router.post("/upload", upload.single("file"),(req,res)=>{
    const saveImage = new imageSchema({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        tag: req.body.folder,
        uploadDate: Date().toString(),
        originalname: req.file.originalname,
        img:
        {
        data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'..','uploads', req.file.originalname)),
        contentType: req.file.mimetype,
        },
    });
    saveImage.save().then((res)=>{
        console.log('image is saved');
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err, 'error has occured');
    });
    res.send('Image is Saved');
})
module.exports = router;
```

Could it be that I need to remove storing the files locally for everything to be okay when I use the Heroku app API? If so, will I still be able to save the buffer of the image in the data field to MongoDB?

Just to reiterate again, all of my code works locally.
I can post to the endpoint, get from it, delete from it.
When I upload a picture, it is saved locally as well and then that file is used to get the data to save.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) which is a mechanism to protect user in-built in all modern browsers.

That is when you open your app running on a local server and try to upload to Heroku the browser won't let you do that to avoid leaking your sensitive data.

Here's how you can fix that:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      "http://localhost:5000",
      "YOUR_HEROKU_APP_HOSTNAME"
    ],
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE", "UPDATE", "PUT", "PATCH"],
  })
);
```

Or enable cors for all requests (for development purposes only)

```
app.use(
  cors()
);
```